# Change variable in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query something like this

```
function List<CustomObject2> GetDataPoint(List<CustomObject> listDataPoints)
{
 if(listDataPoints.Count == 0)
  return;
 var startPoint = new CustomObject();
 startPoint = listDataPoint.First();
 List<CustomObject2> cObjList = from r in listDataPoints
                                where r != null && r.GetDistance(startPoint) > 100
                                select new CustomObject2
                                {
                                  Var1 = r.Var1
                                }.ToList()
 }
```

The problem here is that, in the beginning the startPoint is set to the first object in listDataPoint. However, after the comparison in the query (GetDistance) I want to reassign startPoint to the value of "r" if the Distance is greater than 100.

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do the trick and make `where r != null && r.GetDistance(startPoint) > 100 && (startPoint = r) == r`, but I would go with for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no clean way to do that.

LINQ is essentially a piece of `functional programming` that has been brought into C#. In functional programming *values are immutable* (they cannot be changed). Thanks to being functional and using immutality, LINQ queries can be *lazily evaluated*. It is not uncommon for a LINQ query to be only partly run, or for some parts of the sequence to be evaluated several times. That is safe to do thanks to immutability.

As soon as you want to change a value, you are working against LINQ. In this case you are much better off with a for loop.

Of course there are ways to solve this in a functional manner, as it is possible to solve this in a purely functional language. But in C# it is much cleaner to use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fold:

```
var cObjList = listDataPoints.Where(r => r != null)
    .Aggregate(Tuple.Create(startPoint, new List<CustomObject2>()), (acc, r) => {
        if(r.GetDistance(acc.Item1)) {
            acc.Item2.Add(new CustomObject2 { Var1 = r.Var1 });
            return Tuple.Create(r, acc.Item2);
        }
        else return acc;
    }).Item2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you were not-null checking the elements from `listDataPoints`, so I assume it may contain null objects. In this case, your code may be vulnerable when the `First()` element from the list is empty.

```
//there is no function or procedure in c#;
//function List<CustomObject2> GetDataPoint(List<CustomObject> listDataPoints)
List<CustomObject2> GetDataPoint(List<CustomObject> listDataPoints)
{
    var dataPoints = listDataPoints.Where(r => r != null);

    if (dataPoints.Empty())
        //return; you cant not return anything in a function
        return null; //or return an empty list
        //return new List<CustomObject2>();


    var cObjList = dataPoints.Aggregate(
        new Stack<CustomObject>(),
        (results, r) =>
        {   
            if (r.GetDistance(results.Peek()) > 100)
                results.Add(r);
            return results;
        })
        .Select(r => new CustomObject2(){ Var1 = r.Var1 })
        .ToList();

    //return directly the line above or do more work with cObjList...
}
```

Yet, this is still messy and not easily maintained. Like Anders Abel suggests, you are best to go with the for loop for this case :

```
var cObjList= new List<CustomObject2>();
foreach(var r in dataPoints)
{
    if (r.GetDistance(results.Peek()) > 100)
        results.Add(new CustomObject2(){ Var1 = r.Var1 });
}

//...

return cObjList;
```